# How to do automatic g++ compilation after each save?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm writing simple C++ code (one "cpp" file). Now I compile my program by manually running `g++` from command line. But I was wondering if there is any way to do automatic g++ compilation after each save of file.

I'm using Ubuntu and Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Gulp has a module called watch which does this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are also *much fancier* solutions available:

- [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) compiles and analyses the code in background while you type, for Vim
- [Emacs-ycmd](https://github.com/abingham/emacs-ycmd) is one of several ports to Emacs
- [RStudio IDE](https://www.rstudio.com) does the for C++ code (when though it is an R environment)

You can 'cook' similar things much simpler by using Linux kernel hooks in userspace to *react* whenever a file you watch is saved.  Here you'd simply call `g++`, or as others already said, you probably want `make`.

One of the hooks is inotify; there are several Ubuntu packages accessing this (which I have yet to use).  Here is one:

> ```
> edd@max:~$ apt-cache show entr
> Package: entr
> Priority: optional
> Section: universe/misc
> Installed-Size: 61
> Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
> Original-Maintainer: Yuri D'Elia <wavexx@thregr.org>
> Architecture: amd64
> Version: 2.6-1
> Depends: libbsd0 (>= 0.6.0), libc6 (>= 2.4)
> Filename: pool/universe/e/entr/entr_2.6-1_amd64.deb
> Size: 11310
> MD5sum: 818b54114577b8d15d619577acf52c97
> SHA1: b8422ee12546843f3357c1114bf1f5eeea8c863e
> SHA256: ada9aa2ea218fc9f7a255b576d5069dda06da369ecc4000bb596e398b04eeafd
> Description-en: Run arbitrary commands when files change
>  The Event Notify Test Runner (entr) runs arbitrary commands when
>  files change. Changes are detected through the kqueue/inotify
>  kernel interface.
> Description-md5: 52fe22e37b3719b7c736bf46a6d8c9b7
> Homepage: http://entrproject.org/
> Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
> Origin: Ubuntu
>
> edd@max:~$
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Create a makefile. Most editors have a shortcut keypress that executes `make`.

Comment: It will also become much easier when you start using multiple files (and you will)

Answer (score 1):

You can use make command.

Example: Imagine the file name is test.cpp then you can execute the following command:

```
make test
```

It will automatically compile using g++ as the extension is .cpp

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS Code, you can install the extension `C/C++ Compile Run` for the VS Code. 
Once you change the code, just click `F6` for executing it without passing any additional arguments, or `F7` to type the passing arguments in the Command Palette, which will be passed to the code at the beginning of the execution.

[C/C++ Compile Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run)

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper build system that integrates with your IDE/editor.

There are many to choose from. My personal preference is SCons (http://scons.org/) but there are also options like CMake (https://cmake.org/) or autotools (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System) available or simply a plain Makefile. 
And there are many more less known ones as well.
Check them out and pick what suits your needs best.